# cake php where condition returning all value

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am using cake php 3. I want to fetch data using where condition. But it is showing all data from table without filtering data with where condition. 
Here is my view for inserting where condition data

```
 <?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('category_id', ['options' => $categories,'empty'=>'Choose']);
    ?>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Here is my controller

```
if(!empty($this->request->data['category_id'])){
        $categoryId = $this->request->data();
        $searcehProduct = $this->Products->searchProductsByCategory($categoryId);
        dd($searcehProduct);
    }
```

Here is my ProductTables.php code for where condition.

```
 public function searchProductsByCategory($id){
    $products = TableRegistry::get('Products');
    $query = $products->find('all', [
        'where' => ['category_id' => $id]
    ]);
    return $query;
}
```

TIA

Comment: `$categoryId = $this->request->data();` is an array, maybe you should do `$categoryId = $this->request->getData('category_id');`

Comment: I am getting id with $this->request->data(). Also tried with your given way. still same result. Fetching all data again.

Comment: a note: you don't have to call `TableRegistry::get('Products');` because you are already in a `productsTable` object. Juse use $this

Comment: if I don't call `TableRegistry::get('Products');` it shows me `Table 
 "App\Model\Table\ProductsTable" is not associated with "Products"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is simply that you replaced `'conditions'` with `'where'`

in your controller use

```
$categoryId = $this->request->getData('category_id');
```

and in your table use

```
'conditions' => ['category_id' => $id]
```

and it should works

Anyway this is not the way custom finder are created. But you don't even have to create a custom finder, simply:

**Use a [Dynamic Finder](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#dynamic-finders)**

in fact you can do

```
if($this->request->getData('category_id'))
{
    $categoryId = $this->request->getData('category_id');
    $searcehProduct = $this->Products->findByCategoryId($categoryId);
    dd($searcehProduct);
}
```

no need to alter your Table, this is a dynamically constructed finder

Comment: Great. Dynamic finder part was awesome.